# Azure Data Factory Post Message to Azure Storage Queue failing

Tags: c#, xml, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-storage-queues

I am trying to post a message to an Azure Storage Queue through a Web activity in Azure Data Factory.

I am following the URL format from [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-message). My URL looks as follows, where 'myaccount' and 'myqueue' are replaced with my details:

> https://myaccount.queue.core.windows.net/myqueue/messages?

I am getting a 404 when I try to post a message in the XML Format:

```
<QueueMessage>
    <MessageText>test-message</MessageText>
</QueueMessage>
```

The storage account's authentication method is Access Keys. Do I have to add this to the URL somewhere? I can't figure out why it's 404ing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the SAS Token to the end of the URL and it will solve the problem. Without the SAS Key, any HTTP Request would 404.

You can refer this [MSFT Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/26157/data-lake-and-environments-best-practice-1.html)
To Append a SAS token to each source or destination URL

```
azcopy cp "C:\local\path" "https://account.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1/?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bjqt&srt=sco&sp=rwddgcup&se=2019-05-01T05:01:17Z&st=2019-04-30T21:01:17Z&spr=https&sig=MGCXiyEzbtttkr3ewJIh2AR8KrghSy1DGM9ovN734bQF4%3D" --recursive=true
```

Refer - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5e9f0f-e1c9-4396-b5b3-2caa8fb5076b/azure-file-storage-sas-token?forum=AzureDataLake